# Автозагрузка самописного bash скрипта Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, консоль

Передо мной стоит задача "написать bash script, который будет при старте линукса создавать папку в home и создавать там файл, который через 5 секунд будет запускаться любым текстовым редактором".

Я написал сам скрипт (и сделал его исполнимым), который при запуске из терминала прекрасно работает. Возникли проблемы с автозагрузкой (ее обязательно (условие задания) нужно реализовать через терминал). Пытался сделать через `rc.local`. Сам создал (по этой инструкции https://qinet.ru/2018/05/1649/) этот файл (т.к в 18 версии его нет по умолчанию), сделал его исполнимым, перед `exit 0`, вписал путь до своего скрипта. При запуске системы создается папка и файл, но этот файл не открывается в текстовом редакторе.Также пытался сделать через создание service , все тоже самое файл и папка создается , текстовый редактор не открывается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить? Возможно проблема в моем скрипте.

P.S. Все манипуляции происходят на вирт машине. Может это важно

[image: мой скрипт]

[image: rc.local]

[image: rc.local]

[image: myscr.service]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да у вас система просто не успевает прогрузиться. Этот скрипт запускается еще до того как иксы загрузились и gedit просто стартует с ошибкой. Попробуйте увеличить задержку до минуты и посмотрите как ведет себя система

Comment: Прописал sleep 60 перед gedit не помогло(( Все тоже самое , папка и файл создались , текст. редактор не открылся.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что запускается в другой оболочке, `ps aux` видит скрипт после запуска системы?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее, я пользуюсь линуксом буквально пару дней, и многого не знаю.

Comment: `ps aux | grep "имя вашего скрипта"` - Если в выводе будет отображаться процесс, то скрипт запускается иначе нет

Comment: вроде в выводе появился , скрин прикрепил  к вопросу.

Comment: @Slavikwin, то что запускается в контексте системы инициализации (т.е. rc.local или модуля systemd) ни как не связано с пользовательской сессией. т.е. запустить `gedit` из rc.local не то чтобы невозможно, но это довольно геморройно и принципиально неверно... Ъ-способ для запуска десктопных приложений — создать для своего скрипта `.desktop`-файл в одном из каталогов [XDG autostart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Autostart). ЗЫ: текст с консоли можно копировать, а не вставлять скриншоты...

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А что мне нужно прописать внутри  .desktop файла (создал его в /ect/xdg/autostart ), и как мне его связать со своим скриптом?

Comment: @Slavikwin, на будущее, упоминай имя через собаку имя, если ожидаешь ответа в комментариях...

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему путем добавления файла "мое название".desktop в папку  /ect/xdg/autostart
внутри файла прописал это

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=aaa
Comment=
GenericName=
Keywords=
Exec="путь до моего скрипта"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=
Path=
Categories=
NoDisplay=false
```

Comment: если что, то всё кроме `Name`, `Type` и `Exec` указывать не обязательно...